# Android app to search mp4 videos by metadata

Tags: android, metadata, mp4

I have a set of mp4 files that I need to load onto an SD Card and read in my Android app.

The app needs to be able to search the videos by category, so my plan was to add some category info in the mp4 metadata before loading them (probably in the "description" field) and then use a `ManagedQuery` on the `MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` to find them.

I have updated the "description" field using Adobe Bridge, but when I look at the tags returned by a search, the "description" field is always null. Clearly, the data I'm writing to the mp4 files is not being picked up when Android looks at the video file.

Is there another way I should be writing/searching video metadata?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look at [`MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DESCRIPTION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.html#DESCRIPTION).

You can query the `MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` as you would any other content provider: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html#querying

Comment: I have looked at that field but the results always come back null. I suppose another question here would be how do I write data to the MP4 field before the app loads it so that data will be picked up in the MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DESCRIPTION field?

Answer (score 0):

You can add/delete/lookup metadata fields in MP4 files using JCodec's [MetadataEditor](https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jcodec/movtool/MetadataEditor.java) class.

If you want to add metadata field to MP4 file you can use:

```
MetadataEditor mediaMeta = MetadataEditor.createFrom(new
    File("file.mp4"));
Map<String, MetaValue> meta = mediaMeta.getKeyedMeta();
meta.put("com.android.capture.fps", MetaValue.createFloat(25.));
mediaMeta.save(false); // fast mode is off
```

Alternatively the same can be done from the command line with the CLI tool ([MetadataEditorMain](https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jcodec/movtool/MetadataEditorMain.java)):

```
./metaedit -sk com.android.capture.fps,float=25.0 file.mp4
```

In the Java code you can get the list of metadata like so:

```
MetadataEditor mediaMeta = MetadataEditor.createFrom(new
    File("file.mp4"));
Map<String, MetaValue> meta = mediaMeta.getKeyedMeta();
for (String key : meta.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key + ": " + meta.get(key));
}
```

OR from the command line:

```
./metaedit <file.mp4>
```

Read more about it: http://jcodec.org/docs/working_with_mp4_metadata.html